# Escape Backslash(/) while writing spark dataframe into csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark version 2.4.0. I know that Backslash is default escape character in spark but still I am facing below issue.
I am reading a csv file into a spark dataframe (using pyspark language) and writing back the dataframe into csv.

I have some "//" in my source csv file (as mentioned below), where first Backslash represent the escape character and second Backslash is the actual value.

### Test.csv (Source Data)

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1,"abc//",xyz,Val2
2,"//",abc,Val2
```

I am reading the Test.csv file and creating dataframe using below piece of code:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').schema(schema).option("escape", "\\").options(header='true').load("Test.csv")
```

And reading the df dataframe and writing back to Output.csv file using below code:

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('csv').option("emptyValue", empty).option("header", "false").option("escape", "\\").option("path", 'D:\TestCode\Output.csv').save(header = 'true')
```

### Output.csv

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1,"abc//",xyz,Val2
2,/,abc,Val2
```

In 2nd row of Output.csv, escape character is getting lost along with the quotes(""). 
**My requirement is to retain the escape character in output.csv as well.** Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using the default behavior `.option("escape", "\\")`, change this to:

`.option("escape", "'")`

It should work.

Let me know if this solves your problem!