# How do I make Escape Backslash(/) work while writing spark dataframe into csv?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks

## How do I make Escape Backslash() work while writing spark dataframe into csv?

I find many threads in this subject. I am faciing this issues in DataBricks 11.3, Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12 environment.

As pert of my research, I  followed the following threads.

[escape use with spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171466/escape-backslash-while-writing-spark-dataframe-into-csv)

[How to handle Pipe and escape characters while reading pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503316/how-to-handle-pipe-and-escape-characters-while-reading-pipe-delimited-files-in-p)

Sane CSV processing in Apache Spark
[enter link description here](https://kokes.github.io/blog/2018/05/19/spark-sane-csv-processing.html)

Here is the problem we have. We have CSV file with PIPE (|) delimited that has '|' within data.
After reviewing the above threads/blogs, I know that Backslash is default escape character in spark but still I am facing below issue. I am reading a csv file into a spark dataframe (using pyspark language, DataBricks 11.3, Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12) and writing back the dataframe into csv.

Here is my input data

```
name      |Job         |Address                              |State|Country
John Smith|Truck Driver|"215 Montain Road \| Apt A,  Atlanta"|GA|USA
Henry John|Mechanic|"645 Village Square \| Unit D,   Dover"|DE|USA
Eric Donald|Cook|"737 Brighton Square \| Unit H  Rockville"|MD|USA
Rebecca Jones |Manager|"956 Country Road \|Unit E,   Columbia"|MD|USA
```

1st approach

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("escape", "\\").option("delimiter", "|").csv("dbfs:/FileStore/test.csv")
display(df)
```

Output

```
name      Job           Address                  State Country
John Smith Truck Driver 215 Montain Road \Apt A, Atlanta GA
Henry John Mechanic 645 Village Square \Unit D, Dover DE
Eric Donald Cook 737 Brighton Square \Unit H , Rockville MD
Rebecca Jones Manager 956 Country Road \Unit E, Columbia MD
```

The above is shifting columns to left and dropping contry and retaining backslash()

Tried with adding:

```
.option("quoteMode", "NONE") 
.option("quote", "\u0000") 
.option("quotechar", '\\')
```

The outcome is same.

I wrapped with double quote to input as

For input

```
name      |Job         |Address                              |State|Country
John Smith|Truck Driver|**"215 Montain Road \| Apt A,  Atlanta"**|GA|USA
Henry John|Mechanic|"645 Village Square \| Unit D,   Dover"|DE|USA
Eric Donald|Cook|"737 Brighton Square \| Unit H  Rockville"|MD|USA
Rebecca Jones |Manager|"956 Country Road \|Unit E,   Columbia"|MD|USA
```

Here is the code

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("quotechar", '\\').option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").option("delimiter", "|").csv("dbfs:/FileStore/test-2.csv")
```

display(df)

I am getting:

```
name       Job          Address                               State   Country
John Smith Truck Driver 215 Montain Road \| Apt A,    Atlanta   GA    USA
Henry John Mechanic     645 Village Square \| Unit D, Dover     DE    USA
Eric Donald Cook        737 Brighton Square \| Unit H Rockville MD    USA 
Rebecca Jones Manager   956 Country Road \|Unit E,    Columbia  MD    USA
```

The above output should come without backslash () like.

```
name       Job          Address                               State   Country
John Smith Truck Driver 215 Montain Road | Apt A,    Atlanta   GA    USA
Henry John Mechanic     645 Village Square | Unit D, Dover     DE    USA
Eric Donald Cook        737 Brighton Square | Unit H Rockville MD    USA 
Rebecca Jones Manager   956 Country Road |Unit E,    Columbia  MD    USA
```

I tried to address this issue and fix this reviewing many google search topic no luck so far. I like this forum that addressed this subject in the past so I like to pick up the brain of folks here to show some direction. My requirement is to retain the backslash without escape character as above in output.csv as well. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the Pipe characters are inside quotation marks, do you really need to backslash them? What happens if you don't escape them?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I do not want to retain backslash (\) with them. It looks like spark.read was not complied with rfc4180 for csv. It suppose to drop backslash(\) and load the text with '|'. This is the function of '\|' . It is not working as desired. That is the issue, we are having. I find DB suggest, we need to wrap the data that has '\|' with double quote, but other loaders working without quote wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp_replace function to do that as below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.option("header","true") \
    .option("quotechar", '\\') \
    .option("quote", "\"") \
    .option("escape", "\"") \
    .option("delimiter", "|") \
    .csv("test.csv")

df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----+-------+
|name          |Job         |Address                                 |State|Country|
+--------------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----+-------+
|John Smith    |Truck Driver|215 Montain Road \| Apt A,  Atlanta     |GA   |USA    |
|Henry John    |Mechanic    |645 Village Square \| Unit D,   Dover   |DE   |USA    |
|Eric Donald   |Cook        |737 Brighton Square \| Unit H  Rockville|MD   |USA    |
|Rebecca Jones |Manager     |956 Country Road \| Unit E,   Columbia  |MD   |USA    |
+--------------+------------+----------------------------------------+-----+-------+


df.withColumn('Address', F.regexp_replace('Address', '\\\|', '')).show(truncate=False)
+--------------+------------+---------------------------------------+-----+-------+
|name          |Job         |Address                                |State|Country|
+--------------+------------+---------------------------------------+-----+-------+
|John Smith    |Truck Driver|215 Montain Road | Apt A,  Atlanta     |GA   |USA    |
|Henry John    |Mechanic    |645 Village Square | Unit D,   Dover   |DE   |USA    |
|Eric Donald   |Cook        |737 Brighton Square | Unit H  Rockville|MD   |USA    |
|Rebecca Jones |Manager     |956 Country Road | Unit E,   Columbia  |MD   |USA    |
+--------------+------------+---------------------------------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks .  I opened this thread to figure out, why .option("escape", "\"") not working to load '\|' as '|' . Your work around df.withColumn('Address', F.regexp_replace('Address', '\\\|', '')).show(truncate=False) cannot be adopted when we use generic function approach to load many tables . This workaround make us to do table by table approach. What is the reason .option("escape", "\"")  not working ?